# What is fastest (multithreaded?) way to identify which columns in a matrix are "connected"?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

What is fastest (possible amenable to multithreading as well) way to identify which columns in a matrix are "connected", where "connected" is defined as follows:

at least one non-zero row in column "x" has a non-zero entry in the same row in another column in the matrix. (This process repeats, obviously, until there are no more columns that can be "connected" to each other.)

The matrix is 99.9% sparse and is approximately 1 million columns by 10 million rows.

(FYI: I'm not even too sure what branch of mathematics this falls under, though I suspect it's somewhere in graph theory.)

Comment: And by the way, this is more of a computer science/algorithms question rather than graph theory, and is better suited for those stack exchange forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [union-find structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), with columns being elements. Now run the following algorithm: for each **row** with nonzero elements, take first nonzero element of this row, find a representative of the column containing this element in your union-find structure, and merge remaining nonzero columns in this row with it.

This algorithm runs in $O(n \cdot \alpha(n)))$ time, where $n$ is number of non-zero entries in your matrix. This algorithm can easily be parallelized (e.g. by having each thread consider each row separately), assuming you have parallel union-find implementation, which can be found e.g. in  Anderson, Richard J.; Woll, Heather (1994). Wait-free Parallel Algorithms for the Union-Find Problem. 23rd ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing. pp. 370–380.

Comment: Cool! One follow-up question. How does this compare to graph theory where one has vertices and edges and then one runs what I think are called "clustering" programs to identify the clusters? According to this link (http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/WeakComponentClusterer.html), such a clustering program runs in O(|V| + |E|) time, which appears to be an order of magnitude faster than union-find structure?

Comment: This is really exact same problem. You can view your sparse matrix as a adjacency matrix of a directed graph, then what the above algorithm does is simply finding weakly connected components. You could use BFS-like algorithm to remove the need for the union-find structure, but in practical scenarios, $O(n)$ is no faster than $O(n \cdot \alpha(n))$ -- for any $n$ that can be physically written in our universe, we have $\alpha(n) < 5$.